# ReactJS Header Layout , You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create a Layout component which would render the Header and Footer. I want to create menu list at Header but I got this error from Header.jsx.

```
Error: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>
```

I want to know the solution how to use < Link > at Header.jsx

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Link,Switch,Redirect,browserHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
    class App extends React.Component {

      render() {
            return (
                <Layout>
                    <Router history={browserHistory}>
                        <div>
                            <Route path="/" component={home}/>
                            <Route path="/docs" component={docs}/>
                        </div>
                    </Router>
                </Layout>
            );
        }


    }

export default App;
```

**Layout.jsx**

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                {this.props.children}
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Layout;
```

**Header.jsx**

```
class Header extends React.Component {
      render() {
            return (
             <div>
               <ul>
                 <li><Link to="/">HOME</Link></li>
                 <li><Link to="/docs">DOCS</Link></li>
              </ul>     
            </div>
            );          
      }
 }

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should enclose your `Layout` to `Router` component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Layout>
          <div>
            <Route path="/" component={home} />
            <Route path="/docs" component={docs} />
          </div>
        </Layout>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

basically router should wrap whole app to be able to make routing available  from every where in your app , so what ever component you use at the uppermost , wrap it with router!

even better , you can have an **app.jsx** file that is structured like below and use the concept of shared component btw routes:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router';

render (
  <Router>
    <main>

     // here you can use whatever the shared 
     // component you want to see in all pages
     // for example i want to show my header in all pages
     // so i will use header component here
     <Header />


     <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
     <Route path="/about" component={About} />
     <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
    </main>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define route in index.js

and call route component instead of app in index.js and call app component in route.js